# Function To Delete Table Or Query If Exists

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am attempting to use a Function that checks if a table/query that is passed into the function then delete it.  My issue is that when it hits this line of syntax

```
If TableExists(CStr(tableArray)) Then
```

I get a type mismatch error.  However, if I change the syntax to `If TableExists(CStr(amx)) Then` the value is 0 so the table/query is still not deleted.  What would be the appropriate syntax to pass an array of table names and query names into a function and delete them if they exists?

```
    Function DeleteTables()
   tableArray = Array("Table1", "Table2", "Table3", "Table4")   
   queryArray = Array("Query1", "Query2", "Query3")

    For amx = LBound(tableArray) To UBound(tableArray)
        If TableExists(CStr(tableArray)) Then
            With db.TableDefs
                .Delete CStr(tableArray)
                .Refresh
            End With
        End If
   Next

   For qdi = LBound(queryArray) To UBound(queryArray)
        If TableExists(CStr(queryArray)) Then
            With db.QueryDefs
                .Delete CStr(queryArray)
                .Refresh
            End With
        End If
   Next
End Function
Public Function TableExists(strName As String) As Boolean

   On Error GoTo HandleErr

   Dim db As DAO.Database, tDef As DAO.TableDef

   Set db = CurrentDb

   TableExists = False

   For Each tDef In db.TableDefs
      If tDef.Name = strName Then
         TableExists = True
         Exit For
      End If
   Next tDef

   For Each qDef In db.QueryDefs
    If qDef.Name = strName Then
        TableExists = True
        Exit For
    End If
   Next qDef

ExitFunction:
   db.Close
   Set db = Nothing
   Exit Function

HandleErr:
   TableExists = False
   Resume ExitFunction

End Function

Type Mismatch
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there, you just need to refer to the specific item in the array you're looping through:

Change your current code to:

```
    If TableExists(CStr(tableArray(amx))) Then
        With db.TableDefs
            .Delete CStr(tableArray(amx))
            .Refresh
        End With
    End If
```

and

```
    If TableExists(CStr(queryArray(qdi))) Then
        With db.QueryDefs
            .Delete CStr(queryArray(qdi))
            .Refresh
        End With
    End If
```

You could also use a `For Each` loop in the future, they tend to be easier to understand.

Comment: Ah - so close.  Thank you for the words of wisdom!